# Triggering a pipeline when a pull request is completed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using Azure Pipelines to spin up pull request environments, but we are looking for the best way to delete the environments when the PR is closed (completed/abandoned).

Currently, we use a service hook that fires when the PR status is changed, hitting a custom Azure Function API, which then determines whether to delete the environment and, if so, deletes it.

This seems like it would be a common scenario, so wondering if there are better alternatives?

Comment: I think it's the best way. see also here: https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/02/27/creating-a-dynamic-pull-request-environment-with-azure-pipelines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems like it would be a common scenario, so wondering if there are better alternatives?

Agree with Shayki. What you are doing is the best way, and this is what we are currently using.

That because azure devops does not have the feature to trigger the pipeline after the PR **completed**. Pull request trigger and Build Validation both trigger the pipeline when the PR starts.

So, we need create a service hook to monitor PR status. If the PR status changes, the pipeline is triggered through API or Application.